# Can't adapt the airbrake gem to a Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, airbrake

I am using the airbrake gem like so:

```
require 'airbrake'

Airbrake.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = 'XXXXX'
  config.development_environments = ["development", "test", "cucumber"]
end

use Airbrake::Rack
enable :raise_errors
```

but it still sends airbrake notifications in development.

My environment is saved in `ENV['RACK_ENV']`.

I don't want to hack my way into this, is there an "outside" solution?

Also, I do want to raise exceptions in development - I just don't want them to be sent to airbrake..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`configure`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Configuration) block to only setup Airbrake in production:

```
configure :production do
  require 'airbrake'

  Airbrake.configure do |config|
    config.api_key = 'XXXXX'
  end

  use Airbrake::Rack
end
```

If you have more than one environment you want Airbrake enabled in, you can specify a list, e.g.:

```
configure :production, :staging do
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

@matt's answer should work well, but if you want to do this in the rackup file when setting up the middleware instead of inside the Sinatra app, you could do:

```
use Airbrake::Rack if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == "production"
```

I quite often do this with middleware.